Java local type inference - assigning var to multiple types - confusion
Consider the following snippet below
var i = true ? Integer.valueOf(1) : "ABC"; //this works - why ? 
System.out.println(i instanceof Object); //prints true
System.out.println(i instanceof Integer); //prints true    
System.out.println(i instanceof String); //prints false

System.out.println(i);  //prints 1
i = "haha";  //this compiles ok. How can we assign "haha" to Integer ??

System.out.println(i); //prints "haha"

How on earth can we assign a String to a variable that has already been type inferred as a Integer (since "i instanceof Integer" prints true)?
Why does the compiler allow this and what is being inferred here for i ?
Note, if I say this:
var i2 = 10;
i2 = "lol";

I do get a compile error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int
Addendum:
var x = new Random().nextBoolean() ? 33 : new File("/tmp/");  
System.out.println(x.getClass());
x = 5;
x = "wtf"; //this also is OK!

This also compiles fine and as expected, x.getClass() will sometimes print java.io.File and sometimes java.lang.Integer.
But even when it prints java.io.File, the x = 5 statement always works and compiles ok. Moreover, x = "wtf" also compiles ok.

This question is not similar. The addendum is actually from that link but that other question says that because int and File cannot be coerced to some weird compile time type, it would have to infer as Object. But this example shows it is NOT inferred as Object but rather a java.io.File which is then magically be able to be assigned to a integer - which should not be possible. If it is a java.io.File, there is no way I should be able to assign a integer value to that same variable in the next line.

it is the same. You want to know the static type of the variable. The type the compiler  infers.
GetClass() and instanceof give you the dynamic type - the type that the variable holds at runtime.
The static type of x is Object (or something that can be assigned a String, Int and File)

With local type inference, the compile time type is the run time type right ? This is why they don't allow var at the field/class level, only at the local variable level so there is no risk of runtime types being different than compile time types. And this is why type inference errors happen at compile time (as per my second example), not run time.

No. var is just a tool to let the compiler decide the compile time type

var i = true ? Integer.valueOf(1) : "ABC"; //this works - why ? 

infers the type of the variable i to Object.
And
i instanceof Integer

does not test the type of i, but the type of the instance i is referring to.
Think about this:
String s = "abc";
System.out.println( s instanceof String ); // Output: true

s = null;
System.out.println( s instanceof String ); // Output: false!!!

See here: 15.20.2 The instanceof Operator.
It says, among other things:

If the value of the RelationalExpression is the null reference (§4.1), then the result is false.

And it should be obvious that the type of the variable s had not changed by the assignment of null to it, only its value is now different.

var i = true ? Integer.valueOf(1) : "ABC"; is just Object i = true ? Integer.valueOf(1) : "ABC"; in disguise.
Compiler infer type Object because it is least common type between Integer and String.
